# Send lambda expression from client to server

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, lambda

I have a method that helps to dynamically build a query on a client:

```
public virtual IList<TEntity> Fill(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
{
    includeProperties = includeProperties ?? "";

    var qctx = new TQueryContext
    {
        QueryType = filter == null ? CommonQueryType.FillAll : CommonQueryType.FillWhere,
        Filter = filter,
        OrderBy = orderBy
    };

    qctx.Includes.AddRange(includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    _detachedServerRepo.Read(qctx);

    return qctx.Entities;
}
```

I want to send `qctx` to a server repo which might be on another machine. Since a `TQueryContext` will be typed from `QueryContextBase` defined in part as below I can't serialize it.

```
public class QueryContextBase<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : StateTrackedObject
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public TKey ID { get; set; }
    public string Alf { get; set; }
    public List<TEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    public List<string> Includes { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Filter { get; set; }
    public Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create similar properties to `Filter` and `OrderBy` so I can serialize them and then build up the query in the server repo as below:

```
protected override void FillWhere(TQueryContext qctx)
{
    qctx.Entities.AddRange(this.Fill(qctx.Filter, qctx.OrderBy,
    qctx.GetIncludesAsString()));
}

protected override void FillAll(TQueryContext qctx)
{
    qctx.Entities.AddRange(this.Fill(null, qctx.OrderBy, qctx.GetIncludesAsString()));
}

public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Fill(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
{
    includeProperties = includeProperties ?? "";

    try
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> querySet = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            querySet = querySet.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            querySet = querySet.Include(includeProperty.Trim());
        }

        return (orderBy == null) ? querySet.ToList() : orderBy(querySet).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ThrowDalException<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(OperationType.Read, ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just ship the DLL (library) do the work.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The server will have the server repo code but the client will be sending it filters and orderby's i.e. `x=>x.ID==1234`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right not to want to reinvent the wheel. Check out [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq).

You could solve your problem with this library as below:

In your client repo:

```
public virtual IList<TEntity> Fill(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, 
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "") {

        includeProperties = includeProperties ?? "";
        try
        {
            var qctx = new TQueryContext
            {
                QueryType = filter == null ? CommonQueryType.FillAll : CommonQueryType.FillWhere,
                FilterNode = filter == null ? null : filter.ToExpressionNode(),
                OrderByNode = orderBy == null ? null : orderBy.ToExpressionNode()
            };
```

And then in your QueryContext just add the extra property and convert:

```
 public ExpressionNode FilterNode { get; set; }

 public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Filter 
 { 
    get {
        return FilterNode == null ? null : FilterNode.ToBooleanExpression<TEntity>();
    } 
 }

 public ExpressionNode OrderByNode { get; set; }

 public Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>> OrderBy 
 {
    get {
        return OrderByNode ==  null ? null : OrderByNode.ToExpression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>>();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to serialize a method... any method (lambda, delegate, ...), thus it is not possible to send a method from client to server.

Best you can do is to send a filter to your service, construct the query there and return the result to the client. That is the usual way.

So in your case instead of passing a `Func` which filters the data pass the values which the filter uses.

To elaborate that, consider this example of server-side method:

```
DataType[] GetData(Filter filter, Ordering ordering)
{
    var data = GetDataQuerySomeHow(); //for example in EF Context.Table

    //filter data according to the filter
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.FulltextProperty))
    {
        data = data.Where(a => a.StringProperty.Contains(filter.FulltextProperty));
    }

    //do similar thing for ordering

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

Filter and ordering:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string FulltextProperty { get; set; }
    //some other filtering properties
}

public class Ordering
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public bool Ascending { get; set; }
}
```

Client

```
Filter filter = new Filter()
{
    //fill-in whatever you need
};

Ordering ordering = new Ordering(); //also fill in

var data = GetData(filter, ordering);
//display data somewhere
```

Comment: thx. " pass the values which the filter uses" - which would be impossible / a complete mess with generics I'm guessing :(

Comment: Ok so to be clear, I'd have to re-write GetData for every entity type and every version of query right? Because  the client might want to filter entities that have long or guids for ID, or on 2, 3, 4 different properties. So would that be a separate `GetData` method implementation per query type? i.e. tons of work.

Comment: @lacksInitiative: But possible work :-) By the way it is not really a good practise to have each entity identified by something else... and yes writing a method for each data type seams very usual to me. There often are even multiple methods for each data type - one for getting a single object and one for getting objects according to some filter, ...

Comment: How do you mean each identified by something else? Are you referring to data types for IDs? Some guids, some longs? I'm thinking reflection might be the way out of this. Convert to json "myproperty":"filter1", "filter2", etc; Then reflect from json string to TEntity and build up the query that way. No way I'm writing a method per potential method.

Comment: @lacksInitiative: yes

Comment: The longs are my choice because they're better for indexing, the guids are because part of the datasets is inbound from other systems and they use guids. For your Filters and and Ordering classes, I'd have to create a custom version of each per entity type right?

Comment: Filters probably yes, Ordering not necessarily. If you are ordering just by one column, you may pass just the name of it and the direction of the sorting (asc, desc). You should also thing for your self a bit... I mean, I'm happy to help, but this came quite obvious.